# Findbugs securtity rules in PMD

Tags: findbugs, pmd

There are bunch of security rules in Findbugs. I am trying to use these rule class in PMD.  Currently PMD only provides 2 rules for security out of the box, whereas Findbugs has better options on this. Is it possible to use these Security Experimental rules of Findbugs in PMD's rules.xml file directly?

Comment: No. Findbugs and PMD are two separate tools. They can't utilize each other's detectors.

Comment: Just use both tools - findbugs is better anyway ;-) You can also use the free sonar server which comes with plugins for several tools and more...